# Azure Storage Table - occasionally very slow response time

Tags: c#, azure, .net-core, azure-functions, azure-table-storage

I'm using Azure Tables to store user data and it works well in 95% of time.

But sometimes it causes horrorible response times (17.1s, 21.7s) and it timeouts the caller Azure Function.

As you can see in the two red frame, this happens with `GET .../Tables`.

[image]

Tables are designed by the recommendations of Microsoft and I think that the problem is with seeking for the table and not fetching it's data.

I'm using since a few days explicit tables access (implemented [here](https://gist.github.com/nardieu/24bedee7c488376fb508aee79e808eae)) instead of the standard `[Table]` attribute based parameter injection but it does not help.

Do you have any solution or workaround for this?

Comment: Is there any pattern when you noticed slowness? Does it happen for certain kinds of operations (like querying etc.)? Please edit your question and include details.

Comment: This happens only with GET ..../Tables, I think this is an infrastructural call.

Comment: sounds like something you should engage Azure support

Comment: cool, I'll ask them and will be back

Answer (score 0):

*Maybe* the answer is that Azure Table Storage and Azure Function was in different region (Western Europe and North Europe). Now they are in same region and we do not have any timeout issues *yet*.

Comment: I'm sure - that is the reason of the issue: do not use different regions when accessing Azure Tables.